# Spring request scoped bean population

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, request

I am working on an application that has a custom RequestContext class. So far we are getting this RequestContext in the REST controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/init", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Toto accueil(RequestContext rc) {
  ..
}
```

I would like to declare this class as a "Request scoped" and be able to inject it in other beans, so I added

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
```

When debugging, I am using @Autowire and I see that spring creates a new instance as per request. The problem is that he does not auto populate my bean and all values are null.

How do I tell spring to initialise this request scoped bean with the appropriate values from the real HttpRequest ?

edit: Just found out that currently there is a **HandlerMethodArgumentResolver** that populates the object, inside the controller method call. I am looking to do something like that, but that works on each request.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your description you could use a Filter and in the doFilter function initialize the request scoped bean with the appropriate values from the request.